# Ajax not calling PHP function in Wordpress - URL is valid, action is in data, using wp_die, PHP add_action(...) is correct

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

PHP

```
function customFilter_wpcf7_is_email() { 

$emailIsValid = $_REQUEST['emailValid']; 
echo 'WHAT';
echo 'HI ' . $emailIsValid;
wp_die();

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_customFilter_wpcf7_is_email', 'customFilter_wpcf7_is_email' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_customFilter_wpcf7_is_email', 'customFilter_wpcf7_is_email' );
```

PHP for localizing the ajax url (I placed this under my wp_enqueue_scripts section)

```
 wp_localize_script( 'screenr-child', 'wpcf7_EmailVerify', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

JQUERY:

```
     $.ajax({
            url: wpcf7_EmailVerify.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'customFilter_wpcf7_is_email',
            emailValid: emailValid,
        },
        success: function( response ) {
            console.log('ajax success');
        }
      });
```

For reference, wpcf7_EmailVerify.ajax_url returns "https://whatevermysiteurlis/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" so the url is fine.

**EDITS:**

- I am also seeing "ajax success" in my console log.
- the ajax code is part of a function that's called by a form input change event, and this part is working based on previous tests

Help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: do you mean that the ajax call doesn't execute at all? And you are not getting that `console.log` from `success` callback?

Comment: @Speir

in console log I am getting "ajax success" message, it's just the php function in the action that's not working

Comment: It's really odd. Did you try using `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`? Those `echo` should work in my opinion, is that PHP function echoing anything on the page? Also, can you try `console.log` the response to see what it contains?